# React Native: debug/AndroidManifest.xml vs main/AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, reactjs, xml, react-native, android-manifest

I'm working on a React Native app, and often documentation will refer to `AndroidManifest.xml`. There are two files: `debug/AndroidManifest.xml` and `main/AndroidManifest.xml`. I can usually tell which one they mean by looking at the existing code in each file, but I'm wondering what the difference is between these two files, and specifically, why wouldn't all the code that we apply to one have to be applied to the other as well?